# How to use Python regular expression to process zookeeper logfiles?

Tags: python, regex, logging, apache-zookeeper

Ive got zookeeper logs like the following:

```
2019-09-25 11:16:39,253 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002
2019-09-25 11:16:40,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x36b63c29fbac528, timeout of 10000ms exceeded
```

I am trying to get the following results:

```
log entry 1:
2019-09-25 11:16:39,253 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

log entry 2:
2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002

log entry 3:
2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002
2019-09-25 11:16:40,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x36b63c29fbac528, timeout of 10000ms exceeded
```

I tried using the following regular expression pattern:

```
import re

content = "2019-09-25 11:16:39,253 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception\n \
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002, likely client has closed socket\n \
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)\n \
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)\n \
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n \
2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002\n \
2019-09-25 11:16:40,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x36b63c29fbac528, timeout of 10000ms exceeded\n \
"

pattern = re.compile("(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*)+",re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

match = re.match(pattern, content)
for f in match.groups():
    print(f,"\nEND")
```

but it matched the whole content:

```
2019-09-25 11:16:39,253 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
 EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002, likely client has closed socket
         at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
         at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002
 2019-09-25 11:16:40,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x36b63c29fbac528, timeout of 10000ms exceeded

END
```

does anyone know how to fix this? much would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3}(?:(?!\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3})[\s\S])*
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cOxJw9/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3}` - matches a timestamp of pattern `XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX,XXX` where X is a digit
- `(?:(?!\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3})[\s\S])*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character as long as it does not start with another time-stamp of the format mentioned in pointer 1 above.

You can find the [**working**](https://rextester.com/PLU92171) Python code [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/cOxJw9/1/codegen?language=python).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of what you are attempting, slightly modified:

```
content = """2019-09-25 11:16:39,253 [myid:] - WARN  
[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception\n \
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 
0x16d666b95e10002, likely client has closed socket\n \
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)\n \
    at 
org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)\n \
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n \
2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  
[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002\n \
2019-09-25 11:16:40,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x36b63c29fbac528, timeout of 10000ms exceeded\n \
"""

logs = re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] - (?:TRACE|DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR).*?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] - (?:TRACE|DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR)|$)', content, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(logs)
```

This prints:

```
['2019-09-25 11:16:39,253 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception\n EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002, likely client has closed socket\n         at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)\n         at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)\n         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n ',
 '2019-09-25 11:16:39,260 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.101.231:48311 which had sessionid 0x16d666b95e10002\n ',
 '2019-09-25 11:16:40,000 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x36b63c29fbac528, timeout of 10000ms exceeded\n ']
```

The regex logic used here defines the start of a log line entry as a timestamp followed by a dash and one of the statuses (i.e. `TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`).  The pattern matches using `.*` across lines, in dot all mode, until hitting either the start of another log entry or the end of the input.

Comment: Just to make it clear the only reason I failed to accept your answer is that  Potatoツ 's is a little more comprehensible
But both of your answers are working very well
I am truely sorry for not being able to accept both of your answers!

Comment: @ZhiHe Potatoes taste better than I do when fried :-)